# Destructor can not find member variable, can not delete memory, leading to memory leaks

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, destructor

I implement a class RedBlackTree like this. My questions are at the end.

```
template <  class T,
            class Node = ft::treeNode<T>,
            class Type_Alloc = std::allocator<T>,
            class Node_Alloc = std::allocator<Node>
         >
class RedBlackTree
{
    public:
        typedef T       value_type;
        typedef size_t  size_type;

        RedBlackTree()
        :   _tree_size(0),
            _alloc_node(Node_Alloc()),
            _root(NULL)
        {}

        ~RedBlackTree()
        {
            deleteTree(_root);
        }

        void    deleteTree(Node* node)
        {
            if(node == NULL)
                return ;
            deleteTree(node->left);
            deleteTree(node->right);
            _alloc_node.destroy(node);
            _alloc_node.deallocate(node, 1);
        }

        void    insertValue(const value_type &val)
        {
            Node    *pt = _alloc_node.allocate(1);

            _alloc_node.construct(pt, Node(val));
            _root = RBT_Insert(_root, pt);
        }

        Node*   RBT_Insert(Node* root, Node* pt)
        {...}

    private:
        size_type               _tree_size;
        std::allocator<Node>    _alloc_node;
        Node*                   _root;
```

};

With a struct treeNode like this:

```
template <typename T>
    struct treeNode
    {
        public:
            typedef T   value_type;

            value_type  value;
            treeNode*   parent;
            treeNode*   left;
            treeNode*   right;
            bool        color;

        treeNode(treeNode* parent = NULL, treeNode* left = NULL, treeNode* right = NULL)
        :   value(),
            parent(parent),
            left(left),
            right(right),
            color(BLACK)
        {
        }

        treeNode(const value_type& val, treeNode* parent = NULL, treeNode* left = NULL, treeNode* right = NULL)
        :   value(val),
            parent(parent),
            left(left),
            right(right),
            color(RED)
        {}

        virtual ~treeNode() 
        {         
        }

   };
```

I have problem with the **destructor** of my class RedBlackTree. It has a member method called **insertValue** which allocates memory to a new treeNode. So I thought at the destruction I need to deallocate all the memory, if not it will cause memory leaks.
However it can not compile because of this error:

```
./map/red_black_tree.hpp: In instantiation of ‘void ft::RedBlackTree<T, Node, Type_Alloc, Node_Alloc>::deleteTree(Node*) [with T = ft::pair<const char, int>; Node = std::less<char>; Type_Alloc = std::allocator<ft::pair<const char, int> >; Node_Alloc = std::allocator<std::less<char> >]’: ./map/red_black_tree.hpp:59:27:   required from ‘ft::RedBlackTree<T, Node, Type_Alloc, Node_Alloc>::~RedBlackTree() [with T = ft::pair<const char, int>; Node
= std::less<char>; Type_Alloc = std::allocator<ft::pair<const char, int> >; Node_Alloc = std::allocator<std::less<char> >]’ ./map/map.hpp:69:22:   required from ‘ft::map<Key, T, Compare, Alloc>::map(const key_compare&, const allocator_type&) [with Key = char; T = int; Compare = std::less<char>; Alloc = std::allocator<ft::pair<const char, int> >; ft::map<Key, T, Compare, Alloc>::key_compare = std::less<char>; ft::map<Key, T, Compare, Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<ft::pair<const char, int> >]’ main_map.cpp:122:24:   required from here ./map/red_black_tree.hpp:66:34: error: ‘struct std::less<char>’ has no member named ‘left’; did you mean ‘less’?
                 deleteTree(node->left);
                            ~~~~~~^~~~
                            less ./map/red_black_tree.hpp:67:34: error: ‘struct std::less<char>’ has no member named ‘right’
                 deleteTree(node->right);
                            ~~~~~~^~~~~ <builtin>: recipe for target 'main_map.o' failed
```

1. I don't know why it cannot get the right class of **Node**? It
   thinks that class Node is **std::less** instead of my
   **ft::treeNode**.
2. Is there a better way to do destruction?

Answer:
I declared my variable _rbt in my class map wrongly. It was like that:

```
template <  class Key, class T, class Compare = std::less<Key> >
class map
{
        private:
            Compare                        _compare;
            ft::RedBlackTree<T, Compare>   _rbt;
};
```

the last line of code should be like this:

```
ft::RedBlackTree<T>   _rbt;
```

Comment: Please show the code for `node`.

Comment: The problem is most likely somewhere else and not in the code you provided.

Comment: `RBT_Insert` vs. `BST_Insert` already tells me important information is missing. And this isn't a "can't access my member" case. The error message is telling us  you're actually trying to reference some member `right` from the standard library comparator `std::less<char>`, which has no such member (obviously).  The error isn't about failure to access a member in *your* class.

Comment: @WhozCraig: good catch! Sorry about that, they are the same one, I edited it.
Yes that's exactly the problem, my Node is ft::treeNode, not std::less<char>. I don't know why the compiler does that.

Comment: My guess (from the file names) is that you have a `map` template that derives from `RedBlackTree`. And it's at *that* point the template parameters are confused.

Comment: @BoP: thank you!!! I've just got it. I have a variable of type RedBlackTree in my class map. And it is wrongly declared wit std::less. I think we can close the topic now. I edit my question for the answer.